# Truncate Leading Zeroes and Padding Equal Number of Spaces to particular fields in UNIX

Tags: unix, sed

How to remove leading zeroes from particular columns and padding with equal number of spaces.

```
A001|XYZ|00001|00234|0090
B001|XYZ|00010|00234|0990
C001|XYZ|00321|00234|0345
D001|XYZ|05001|00234|0777
```

Fields 3 and 5 are integer fields and output should be as below-

```
A001|XYZ|1....|00234|90..
B001|XYZ|10...|00234|990.
C001|XYZ|321..|00234|345.
D001|XYZ|5001.|00234|7...
```

('.' represent spaces)

Comment: Read about printf formatting strings. The same concept as I used in your previous question can do this with the right formatting string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very trivial using `awk` and `printf`:

```
awk '
BEGIN { FS = OFS = "|" }
{   len = length ($3)
     $3 = sprintf ("%*-d", len, $3)
    len = length ($5)
     $5 = sprintf ("%*-d", len, $5)
}1' file
A001|XYZ|1    |00234|90
B001|XYZ|10   |00234|990
C001|XYZ|321  |00234|345
D001|XYZ|5001 |00234|777
```

Identify the length of the field. Using `sprintf` assign the value to the same column. Using `*` allows us to capture the number of spaces required from the length of the field taken from argument.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed ':again
   s/^\(\([^|]*\|\)\{2\}\)0\([0-9]*\)/\1\3 /
   t again
   s/^\(\([^|]*\|\)\{4\}\)0\([0-9]*\)/\1\3 /
   t again' YourFile
```

easier for any columns (if needed)

```
sed ':again
   s/\|0\([0-9]*\)/\1 /g
   t again' YourFile
```